# How to append to powershell Hashtable value?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, hashtable, smo

I am interating through a list of `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server` objects and adding them to a hashtable like so:

```
$instances = Get-Content -Path .\Instances.txt
$scripts = @{}

foreach ($i in $instances)
{
    $instance = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $i
    foreach($login in $instance.Logins)
    {
        $scripts.Add($instance.Name, $login.Script())       
    }
}
```

So far so good. What I want to do now is append a string to the end of the hashtable value. So for an $instance I want to append a string to the hashtable value for that $instance. How would I do that? I have started with this, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track:

```
foreach ($db in $instance.Databases)
{       
    foreach ($luser in $db.Users)
    {
        if(!$luser.IsSystemObject)
        {
            $scripts.Set_Item ($instance, <what do I add in here?>)
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: By the way it doesn't have to be a HashTable - perhaps a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string]` would be better?

Comment: Mark: Generics in PowerShell are a bit icky, though. Most of the time I'd say if you don't desperately need them, don't use them as the code is actually less clear.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$h= @{}

$h.add("Test", "Item")
$h

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                   
Test                           Item                                                                                                                                                    

$h."Test" += " is changed"
$h

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                   
Test                           Item is changed
```

Comment: `$h.Test` is actually enough. If there are no weird characters in the key name the quotes aren't necessary.

Comment: Yes. Agreed. I wanted to show the quotes so others knew that was an option.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this code.

```
$instances = Get-Content -Path .\Instances.txt
$scripts = @{}

foreach ($i in $instances)
{
    $instance = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $i
    foreach($login in $instance.Logins)
    {
        $scripts[$instance.Name] = @($scripts[$instance.Name]) + $login.Script().ToString()
    }
}
```

.

```
foreach ($db in $instance.Databases)
{
    foreach ($luser in $db.Users)
    {
        if(!$luser.IsSystemObject)
        {
            $scripts[$instance] = @($scripts[$instance]) + $luser.Script().ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

The result will be a hash table with each instance as a key, and an array of strings where each string is the T-SQL script for a user.

Answer (score 0):

The `.Script()` method returns a string collection. There's probably a more elegant way of doing it, but replacing

```
$scripts.Set_Item ($instance, <what do I add in here?>)
```

with

```
$val = $scripts[$instance]
$val.Add("text to add")
$scripts.Set_Item($instance, $val)
```

should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
$test = @{}

$test.Hello = "Hello World"

Write-Host "message from $($test.Hello)"

$test.Hello += " Cosmonaut"

Write-Host "message from $($test.Hello)"
```

[image: output]

Comment: @james.garriss no, I don't think so. I am using dot notation with instant properties, other answers may be using hash index which are similar but not the same. they are using 'add' message and I am not. this is a really petty moderation. moderation for the sake of moderation is super meta and annoying.